# How to undo update in windows 10 from command prompt

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Last night I shut down my computer, which is running Windows 10, but it did an update before it shut down. This morning, when I tried to open, the GUI of the lock screen looked kind of different. After I logged in, the screen is all black except for a small white box that didn't do anything. Using the hotkey Ctrl+Shift+Esc, I am able to open the task manager, and under the "files" tab I can click "run new task" and can open MS DOS (as administrator). I used sfc /SCANNOW but it said no error occurred. When I used "run new task" and clicked "browse," all my files are there. When I connected an external hard drive to try to copy all my important files, the computer didn't recognize the hard drive. Another weird thing that occurred is that even though I have never used Linux before, there is a "Linux" tab on the left with the penguin logo, and when I clicked it it is empty. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? The update is most likely the newest one as of today, July 6, 2021 (not sure specifics, it automatically did it). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is Exporer running? That is, can you open the Task Manager, run a new Explorer process (`explorer.exe`) and see a difference?

Comment: @Anaksunaman well explorer is not *really* running but I can browse in task manager, and the icons look different. are you implying it updated to windows 11? Perhaps it did. Is it possible to undo it?

Comment: What update did you install exactly?  Some updates (Servicing Stacks) cannot be uninstalled.  You can [edit] your question to include this necessary information. Be sure you mention what version of Windows 10 you are using.  The last thing you want to do is update to Windows 11, it is unstable, if you update to Windows 11 expect to be forced to perform a clean install in 3 months.  Have you tried to run explorer.exe from Task Manager?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry but I'm not sure about the last version of Windows 10 that was installed because I honestly wasn't paying attention. it automatically updated when I shut down my computer. And no, explorer.exe didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened command prompt as administrator, went to

*C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows*

and deleted the files

*appsfolder.menu.itemdata-ms* and *appsfolder.menu.itemdata-ms.bak*

and restarted. It was successful.